# Submodule Criterion for Rings without 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In section 10.1 (page 342) of Dummit & Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, they state the following:

> **Proposition 1.** *(The Submodule Criterion)* Let $R$ be a ring and let $M$ be an $R$-module. A subset $N$ of $M$ is a submodule of $M$ if
>   and only if
>
> **(1)** $N \neq \emptyset$, and
>
> **(2)** $x + ry \in N$ for all $r \in R$ and for all $x, y \in N$.

This proposition states that $R$ is simply a ring, not that it has identity. In the next definition, they specifically state "a commutative ring with identity." In the definition of a module at the beginning of the section, they emphasize that $R$ is "not necessarily commutative nor with 1." However, the proof proceeds as follows:

> *Proof:* If $N$ is a submodule, then $0 \in N$ so $N \neq \emptyset$. Also $N$ is closed under addition and is sent to itself under the action of
>   elements of $R$. Conversely, suppose (1) and (2) hold. Let $r = -1$
>   and apply the subgroup criterion (in additive form) to see that $N$ is
>   a subgroup of $M$. In particular, $0 \in N$. Now let $x = 0$ and apply
>   hypothesis (2) to see that $N$ is sent to itself under the action of
>   $R$. This establishes the proposition.

Clearly, by letting $r = -1$, this proof assumes that $R$ has identity.

Now, consider $R = 4\mathbb{Z}$, which is a ring without identity. Then, $4 \mathbb{Z}$ acts on the set $M = \mathbb{Z}$ by $r \cdot m = rm$, that is, by normal multiplication. Clearly, distributivity and associativity are inherited, so $\mathbb{Z}$ is a left $4\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Take $N = 4\mathbb{Z} \cup (3 + 4\mathbb{Z})$, that is, the subset of integers congruent to $3$ or $0$ modulo $4$. Certainly, $N \neq \emptyset$. If $x, y \in N$, then $x + ry \equiv x \pmod{4}$, for any $r \in R$, so that $x + ry \in N$.

Therefore, by Proposition 1, $N$ should be a $4\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Z}$. But $N$ is not an abelian group because $3 \in N$ but $-3 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ is not in $N$.

I have checked the errata, but I did not see this listed. I have also checked other textbooks, but it can be difficult to determine when they are assuming identity or not, since there is often a sentence somewhere earlier in the book that says all rings are assumed unital. I have also found the following alternative definition:

> *Definition*. Let $N$ be a subset of the $R$-module $M$. Then $N$ is a submodule of $M$ if and only if the following hold:
>
> (1) $N \neq \emptyset$, and
>
> (2) $rx + sy \in N$ for all $r, s \in R$ and $x, y \in N$.

However, with this definition, similar counterexamples can still be found.

**Questions**:

- Am I correct in my assessment that this is an error?
- Is there a "Submodule Criterion" that works for rings $R$ without identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $N$ should be closed under all the structure specified by $M$,
that is $N$ is a $+$-subgroup of $M$ and $N$ is closed under scalar multiplication. In total, we should have

1. $N\neq \emptyset$
2. $N-N\subseteq N$
3. $R\cdot N \subseteq N$

Unless I'm forgetting something important...

Comment: I more wanted to know if there's a thing called the "Submodule Criterion" for rings without identity. In other words, if I'm reading something, and it says, "by the Submodule Criterion," should I now know that they are assuming R is unital?

Comment: @user144527 There is a "sub-? criterion" for every algebraic notion ? and even beyond that. However I have not checked the book you mentoined yet, but it seems to me that they really are working with unital rings there. Otherwise, that submodule criterion just looks wrong.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of thought, I think you are correct, this is an oversight as I believe the authors intended the ring to be unital - as clearly evidenced by their proof and their restriction that all the exercises in the chapter should be assumed to be unital rings. For your second question, I believe a minimal requirement would be to use your second definition and add a 3rd condition that the group action by $R$ is *faithful* on $N$, or that the kernel of the ring action on $N$ is empty - so that we can guarantee the additive inverse of all elements in $N$ are also in $N$ (I will let you think about that if it is not immediate) and thus can use the additive subgroup criterion to finish the proof. I can't think of a weaker condition than that. Nice observation.

Comment: Did you mean transitive instead of faithful?